# psql \copy "No such file or directory" if file is a variable

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to copy a .csv file into a postgresql table, where the file name is a variable. It fails with a "no such file or directory" error if \COPY and a user other than postgres is used. However, the copy succeeds if COPY and the postgres user is used.
The failing script:

```
martin@opensuse1:~> ./test1.sh
Null display is "¤".
'/home/martin/20180423.csv'
psql:load.sql:2: :load_csv: No such file or directory
martin@opensuse1:~> cat test1.sh
load_csv=/home/martin/20180423.csv
psql -d test1 -e -f load.sql --variable=load_csv="'$load_csv'"
martin@opensuse1:~> cat load.sql
\echo :load_csv
\copy test_table (col1, col2, col3) FROM :load_csv delimiter ';' encoding 'LATIN1' NULL '';
martin@opensuse1:~>
```

The working script:

```
martin@opensuse1:~> ./test1.sh
Null display is "¤".
'/home/martin/20180423.csv'
copy test_table (col1, col2, col3) FROM '/home/martin/20180423.csv' delimiter ';' encoding 'LATIN1' NULL '';
COPY 3
martin@opensuse1:~> cat test1.sh
load_csv=/home/martin/20180423.csv
psql -w postgres -d test1 -e -f load.sql --variable=load_csv="'$load_csv'"
martin@opensuse1:~> cat load.sql
\echo :load_csv
copy test_table (col1, col2, col3) FROM :load_csv delimiter ';' encoding 'LATIN1' NULL '';
martin@opensuse1:~>
```

What can I do to make this script run without having to use the postgres user?

Martin

Comment: \copy works when the file name is entered hard coded, and not via --variable. The input csv filename changes, so I need to use the --variable qualifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the psql variables are not substituted in the \copy command.
A solution is to write the \copy command to a file and execute that file.

The part from my script (load the table par from the tsv-file with the
name stored in :input_file) is:

```
    -- Tuples only:
    \t on
    -- Output file:
    \o load_cmd.sql
    select concat('\copy par from ''', :'input_file', '.tsv'';');
    -- Standard output again:
    \o
    -- Normal decoration of tables:
    \t off
    -- Now execute the file with the \copy command:
    \i load_cmd.sql
```

Comment: I now use a workaround of creating a symbolic link to a unique filename, run the copy using that filename and remove the symlink afterwards.

Comment: no need to store the generated command string in a file, a variable would be enough: `\set cmd '\\copy par from ' :'input_file' '.tsv'` then execute it with `:cmd`